# Fill Down with linked values

Tags: excel, vba

I need to fill down a value in `Sheet 1 Cell A2` with `=Sheet 2 Cell A2` until the linked value is blank. I dont really know what to do.

I got so far so that I only need zeros in the fields:

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
          
    Set wsh = Worksheets("List with Weights")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
          
    i = 2
    
    While (wsh.Cells(i, 1)) <> ""
        wsh.Cells(i, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "='Sample Weight'!RC[0]"
        wsh.Cells(i, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "='Sample Weight'!RC[0]"
        wsh.Cells(i, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "='IS Weight'!RC[-1]"
        i = i + 1
    Wend
     
    ' Selects cell down 1 row from active cell.
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Columns("A:C").Select
    Columns("A:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, there is no need for a loop. Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsThis As Worksheet
    Dim wsThat As Worksheet
    Dim wsOther As Worksheet
    
    '~~> Set your relevant worksheets
    Set wsThis = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List with Weights")
    Set wsThat = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sample Weight")
    Set wsOther = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IS Weight")
    
    '~~> Find the last row in Col A of Sample Weight worksheet
    Dim wsThatLRow As Long
    wsThatLRow = wsThat.Range("A" & wsThat.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    '~~> Insert the formula in 1 go in the relevant range
    With wsThis
        .Range("A2:A" & wsThatLRow).Formula = "='" & wsThat.Name & "'!A2"
        .Range("B2:B" & wsThatLRow).Formula = "='" & wsThat.Name & "'!B2"
        .Range("C2:C" & wsThatLRow).Formula = "='" & wsOther.Name & "'!B2"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, This works like hoped that it stops right there but the Value in the Column C equals the Value from Sheet "IS Weight" Column B

Comment: I have updated the post. You may have to refresh to see it. Let me know if this is what you want?

Comment: Also, I am assuming that the last row will be same in `Sample Weight` and `IS Weight`. If not, then recalculate the last row using `wsThatLRow = wsOther.Range("A" & wsOther.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` before using it in `.Range("C2:C" & wsThatLRow).Formula = "='" & wsOther.Name & "'!B2"`

Comment: EXACTLY! Thank you so frigging much :) :) :) Well there are the same number of rows in the 2 sheets

Comment: Glad to be of help :)